# show which file Logback is reading and in what file path?

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

In case of Logback is reading some logback.xml file, is it possible to show which file it is reading and in what file path?

I have problem with using logback and an idea comes my mind, maybe some third party jar files gives own logback.xml and instead of mine, its file is used by Logback as configuration file.

If I learn internally which file and in what path Logback is using as configuration file, I may produce some solution so that it will eventually use my own logback.xml configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Followed the source code and finally ended up here:

```
public static void printLogConfigUrl() {

    ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList wl =
            ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.ConfigurationWatchListUtil.getConfigurationWatchList(
            (ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext) org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory());
    System.out.println(wl.getMainURL());
}
```

For reference, I started at [ContextInitializer](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/util/ContextInitializer.java) which let to [GenericConfigurator](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/joran/GenericConfigurator.java) which let to the [ConfigurationWatchListUtil](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/joran/util/ConfigurationWatchListUtil.java) shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the @vanOekel, I have found a way to emit which file Logback used for configuration;

```
LoggerContext loggerContext = ((ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) logger).getLoggerContext();
System.out.println(ConfigurationWatchListUtil.getMainWatchURL(loggerContext));
```